# How to "ungroup" the columns in a python dataframe resulting from df.resample()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I resample trades data using the following statement

```
ohlc = trades.resample('1H').agg({'price': 'ohlc', 'volume': 'sum'})
```

the resulting dataframe contains a hierarchy of columns, grouped by price and volume:

```
                       price                                 volume
                        open     high      low    close      volume
dtime                                                              
2021-06-30 22:00:00  34826.1  34923.4  34644.9  34875.8   68.884098
2021-06-30 23:00:00  34899.1  35208.8  34899.1  35046.2   83.506264
2021-07-01 00:00:00  35070.4  35070.4  34719.0  34761.5   81.766629
```

How can I convert this into a regular dataframe with a flat list of columns like this, so that I can access the columns directly by `ohlc.open` etc.:

```
                     open     high      low    close      volume

dtime                                                              
2021-06-30 22:00:00  34826.1  34923.4  34644.9  34875.8   68.884098
2021-06-30 23:00:00  34899.1  35208.8  34899.1  35046.2   83.506264
```

I'm currently using the following "brute force" code which achieves the result, but I'd be very surprised if there isn't an easier/cleaner way:

```
print(ohlc.price.open)  # displays the "close" column but requires a redundant .price, .volume etc.

ohlc['open'] = ohlc.price.open
ohlc['high'] = ohlc.price.high
ohlc['low'] = ohlc.price.low
ohlc['close'] = ohlc.price.close
ohlc['volume1'] = ohlc.volume.volume
ohlc = ohlc[['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume1']]
ohlc['volume'] = ohlc.volume1
ohlc = ohlc[['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']]

print(ohlc.open)  # now this displays the "open" column! The column label is missing, but I don't mind that.
```

Comment: use `ohlc=ohlc.droplevel(0,1)`

Comment: Thanks for the hint! But it results in `ValueError: Cannot remove 1 levels from an index with 1 levels: at least one level must be left.`
I tried various combinations of arguments for droplevel(), but haven't found one that works. My ohlc also looks different from the examples in https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html - I don't have anything equivalent to the "level_1" and "level_2" from their example.

Comment: That doesn't sound right: Are you sure you have tried it on a frame that has multileveled columns? Maybe you accidentally applied it to the frame you've already de-leveled? `.droplevel(0, 1)` does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes! I tried again and it works! I apologize, must have used the wrong frame before as suggested. Thanks @AnuragDabas and Timus for insisting ;), highly appreciated!